# using R to update a .csv file based on conditional formatting

Tags: conditional-statements

I want to use R to create or update a new column in a dataframe based on information that exists in other columns in the dataframe.  For example, I have dam source information for lambs born in 2017, but not 2018, even though the same dams were used to generate both drops of lambs.

I want to use the information from the dams in 2017 to update the `damsource2` field in the file so that I have `damsource2` for all dams. There is a complication due to dams not having the same number of offspring year to year and a small number did not have lambs in 2017 but did in 2018 so I need to be able to code these as NA.

I want to be able to populate the `damsource2` field by matching the `damtag` across the years and then have the `damsource` information included in `damsource2` for both years. I have looked at if-else statements but as this is my first attempt at writing code like this I am lost. I would appreciate help generating appropriate code to solve this problem.

I have attached a small subset of the much larger CSV file I would like to use to generate the dataframe and create the new field.

[Subset of current .csv file to be updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCAAa.png)

Comment: Please elaborate on the `damsource2` field, like where did it come from and what does it do?

Comment: damsource2 is a genetic grouping based on three identified genetic groups found in the dams that generated the progeny (lambtag). My apologies, the end of the field names have been cut out of the csv example file as it is just an image of the data file, the first column named damsource is the third column, the damsource2 that I am looking to populate based on damtag and damsource is the fifth column.